# Google Maps Markers refreshing weirdly when bounds changed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vue-cli

I have finished my project about a restaurant app using Vue and Google Maps.
Everything works but I still have a bug I didn't manage to correct with the markers.

When I move on the map and the bounds change, some markers disappear. When I come back on their position, they will not appear again all the time.
If I move fast with the cursor, there is a higher chance that they appear again on the map.

I checked in the Vue console of Chrome and everything is fine here.
The markers are disappearing and appearing when in the bounds of the map, even if not always visible on screen.

The API is divided between three components, and I also use VueX.

Google Map Component (create the map)

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="google-map" v-bind:id="mapName" ref="mainMap">
    </div>
<!--    Tuto ici : https://itnext.io/new-unnamed-post-8da9cdbf5df3-->
    <template v-if="Boolean(this.google) && Boolean(this.map)">
      <slot :google="google" :map="map"></slot>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  // Utilisation du plugin pour charger de manière asynchrone l'API
  const GoogleMapsAPILoader = require('google-maps-api-loader');

  export default {
    name: 'google-map',
    props: [
      'name',
      'defaultCenter'
    ],
    data: function() {
      return {
        google: null,
        mapName: this.name + "-map",
        userCoord: {},
        markers: [],
        map: null,
        bounds: null,
        infoWindow: null,
      }
    },
    // Petit plugin pour loader de manière asynchrone l'API Google et éviter des erreurs
    async mounted() {
      const google = await GoogleMapsAPILoader({
        apiKey: 'APIKEY&libraries=places'
      })
      this.google = google
      // Appel de InitMap, et des listeners
      this.initMap();
      this.addChangeBoundsListener();
      this.openAddRestaurant();
    },
    methods: {
      // Initialise la carte
      initMap() {
        // Pour y faire référence plus facilement
        const element = this.$refs.mainMap
        const options = {
          center: this.defaultCenter,
          zoom: 12,
        }
        this.map = new this.google.maps.Map(element, options);
        this.infoWindow = new this.google.maps.InfoWindow;
        // Emet google et map à MainMap
        this.$emit('map-initialized', {
          google: this.google,
          map: this.map
        })
      },
      addChangeBoundsListener() {
        // Pour utiliser les bounds pour l'affichage des restaurants dans la liste
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'bounds_changed', (event) => {
          this.$emit('map-bounds-changed')
        })
      },
      openAddRestaurant() {
        // Emet l'event pour ajouter un restaurant au click sur la carte
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', (event) => {
          this.$emit('map-clicked', event);
        })
      },
    }
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
  @media screen and (min-width: 446px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .main {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
  }

  .google-map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #26A65B;
    border-radius: 2rem;
  }
</style>
```

Google Markers Component (show the markers):

```
<template>
  <div class="google-markers">

  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    name: 'google-markers',
    props: {
      google: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      },
      map: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      },
      marker: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        mapMarker: null
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      // Création des markers
      this.mapMarker = new this.google.maps.Marker({
        position: this.marker.position,
        map: this.map,
        marker: this.marker,
        icon: this.getIconUrl(this.marker.type)
      })
      // Ajout du listener click sur icon ouvre composant ReadComments
      this.mapMarker.addListener('click', () => {
          if (this.marker.type !== 'user') {
            this.$router.push({
              path: `/read-comments/${this.marker.id}`
            });
          }
        });
    },
    // Pour supprimer les markers avant de les redessiner
    beforeDestroy() {
      if (this.marker.type === 'user') console.log('je disparais');

      this.mapMarker.setMap(null)
    },
    methods: {
      // Dessiner les markers
      getIconUrl(markerType) {
        let icon
        switch (this.marker.type) {
          case 'restaurant':
            icon = 'https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/restaurant-table.png';
            break;
          case 'user':
            console.log('user')
            icon = 'https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/marker.png';
            break;
          default:
            icon = 'https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/48/000000/record.png';
            break;
        }
        return icon
      }
    },
    computed: {
      // Redessine les markers
      refreshIcon() {
        this.getIconUrl(this.marker.type);
      }
    }
  }
</script>


<style scoped>

</style>
```

MainMap (use the two other components, ask geolocation, create markers, call Google Places):

```
<template>
  <google-map :center="customCenter" :defaultCenter="defaultCenter" @map-initialized="initialize" @map-bounds-changed="selectVisibleMarker" @map-clicked="openAddRestaurant">
    <template slot-scope="{ google, map }">
      <google-markers v-for="marker in markers" :marker="marker" :map="map" :google="google"></google-markers>
      <google-markers v-if="userMarker !== {}" :marker="userMarker" :map="map" :google="google"></google-markers>
    </template>
  </google-map>
</template>

<script>
  import GoogleMap from './GoogleMap'
  import GoogleMarkers from './GoogleMarkers'

  export default {
    components: {
      GoogleMap,
      GoogleMarkers
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        google: null,
        mapName: this.name + "-map",
        userCoord: {},
        userMarker: {
          type: 'user'
        },
        marker: null,
        map: null,
        bounds: null,
        infoWindow: null,
        position: {
          lat: null,
          lng: null
        },
        defaultCenter: {
          lat: 48.842702,
          lng: 2.328434
        },
        customCenter: {
          lat: null,
          lng: null
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      // Vient de GoogleMap
      initialize(data) {
        this.map = data.map
        this.google = data.google

        this.askGeolocation()
      },
      // Demande si l'utilisateur accepte la géolocalisation, et recentre la carte sur sa position si acceptée.
      askGeolocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            const pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            this.customCenter = pos
            this.userCoord = pos
            this.userMarker = {
              ...this.userMarker,
              position: pos,
            }
            this.map.setCenter(this.customCenter)
            this.setPlaces(pos);

          }, () => {
            this.handleLocationError(true, this.defaultCenter);
            this.setPlaces(this.defaultCenter);
          });
        } else {
          this.handleLocationError(false, this.defaultCenter);
          this.setPlaces(this.defaultCenter);
        }
      },
      handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, pos) {
        this.map.setCenter(pos)
      },
      // selectVisibleRestaurant dépend du tri et de la zone d'affichage de la carte, et est utilisé par Map et List
      selectVisibleMarker() {
        this.$store.commit('setBoundsValue', this.map.getBounds())
        this.$store.commit('selectVisibleRestaurant')
      },
      // ouvre le composant AddRestaurant avec lat et lng en query
      openAddRestaurant(event) {
        this.$router.push({
          path: '/add-restaurant/',
          query: {
            lat: event.latLng.lat(),
            lng: event.latLng.lng()
          }
        });
      },
      // Google Places
      setPlaces(location) {
        const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
        // Appel l'action getData du Store
        this.$store.dispatch('getData', {
          service,
          location
        })
      }
    },
    computed: {
      // Génère les markers
      markers() {
        const markersArray = [
          ...this.$store.getters.getRestaurantList.map((restaurant, index) => {
            return {
              id: restaurant.ID,
              position: {
                lat: parseFloat(restaurant.lat),
                lng: parseFloat(restaurant.long),
              },
              type: 'restaurant'
            }
          })
        ]
        if (this.userMarker !== {}) {
          markersArray.push(this.userMarker)
        }
        return markersArray
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Store:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import restaurantFactory from '../interfaces/restaurantFactory';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    restaurantList: [],
    visibleRestaurant: [],
    sortValue: [],
    boundsValue: {}
  },
  getters: {
    // Obtenir l'ID des restaurants
    getRestaurantById: (state) => {
      return (id) => {
        const restaurantIndex = getRestaurantIndex(state.restaurantList, id);
        console.log({
          id,
          restaurantIndex
        });
        return state.restaurantList[restaurantIndex];
      };
    },
    getRestaurantList: state => {
      return state.visibleRestaurant;
    },
    getSortValue: (state) => {
      return state.sortValue;
    },
    getBoundsValue: (state) => {
      return state.boundsValue;
    },
    // Calcul de la moyenne des notes données en commentaires
    // getRestaurantAvgRating: (state) => {
    //   return (id) => {
    //     const restaurantIndex = getRestaurantIndex(state.restaurantList, id);
    //     const {
    //       ratings
    //     } = state.restaurantList[restaurantIndex];

    //     return computeAvgRatings(ratings)
    //   };
    // }
  },
  mutations: {
    setRestaurantList: (state, {
      list
    }) => {
      state.restaurantList = list;
    },
    // Définit les restaurants à afficher en fonction des limites de la carte et du tri par moyenne
    selectVisibleRestaurant(state) {
      const bounds = state.boundsValue;
      const range = state.sortValue;
      state.visibleRestaurant = state.restaurantList.filter((restaurant) => {
        let shouldBeVisible = true;
        let isInMap = true;
        let isInRange = true;
        // Limites cartes
        if (bounds) {
          isInMap = restaurant.long >= bounds.ga.j && restaurant.long <= bounds.ga.l && restaurant.lat >= bounds.na.j && restaurant.lat <= bounds.na.l;
          shouldBeVisible = shouldBeVisible && isInMap;
        }
        // Moyenne des notes
        if (range && range.length === 2) {
          isInRange = restaurant.avgRating >= range[0] && restaurant.avgRating <= range[1];
          shouldBeVisible = shouldBeVisible && isInRange;
        }

        return shouldBeVisible;
      });
    },
    setBoundsValue: (state, bounds) => {
      state.boundsValue = bounds;
    },
    setSortValue: (state, range) => {
      state.sortValue = range;
    },
    // Ajoute un restaurant en ajoutant automatiquement un champ avgRating et un ID (le dernier +1)
    addRestaurant: (state, { newRestaurant }) => {

      const ratings = newRestaurant.ratings || []

      const restaurantToAdd = {
        ...newRestaurant,
        ratings,
        avgRating: computeAvgRatings(ratings),
        ID: getLastId()
      }

      state.restaurantList.push(restaurantToAdd)
      state.visibleRestaurant.push(restaurantToAdd)

      function getLastId() {
        const lastId = state.restaurantList.reduce((acc, restaurant) => {
          if (acc < restaurant.ID) {
            return restaurant.ID
          }
          return acc
        }, 0)

        return lastId + 1
      }
    },
    // Ajoute un commentaire
    addComment: (state, {
      restaurantId,
      comment
    }) => {
      const restaurantIndex = getRestaurantIndex(state.restaurantList, restaurantId);

      state.restaurantList[restaurantIndex].ratings.push({
        ...comment
      })

      const restaurantRating = computeAvgRatings(state.restaurantList[restaurantIndex].ratings);
      state.restaurantList[restaurantIndex].avgRating = restaurantRating;
    }
  },
  // Fait appel à restaurantFactory et ajoute les restaurants de la liste JSON et de GooglePlaces
  actions: {
    getData: async function (context, { service, location }) {
      const restaurantList = await restaurantFactory.getRestaurantList(service, location)

      restaurantList.forEach((newRestaurant) => context.commit('addRestaurant', { newRestaurant }))
    },
  }
});

// Fonction helper pour getRestaurantById
function getRestaurantIndex(restaurantList, id) {
  return restaurantList
    .findIndex((restaurant) => restaurant.ID === parseInt(id))
}
// Fonction helper pour getRestaurantAvgRating
function computeAvgRatings (ratings) {
  const avgRating = ratings.reduce((acc, rating) => {
    return acc + (rating.stars / ratings.length);
  }, 0);
  return Math.round(avgRating);
}
```

In Google Markers and MainMap, the markers are handled with Computed.
I can't identify from where comes my problem.

To sum up: if the markers are dynamically deleted and created (for Vue and visible in the Chrome Dev Console) when their location is in the bounds or not, they are not necessarily visible on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to this problem:

```
<google-markers v-for="marker in markers" :key='marker' :marker="marker" :map="map" :google="google"></google-markers>
```

Just adding the :key corrected this bug and the markers are now showing correctly on the map.

Answer (score 0):

If markers are reconstructed when bounds changed, then all markers has to remove/delete first and then reset on map.

Comment: done here: beforeDestroy() {

      this.mapMarker.setMap(null)
    },